# Angular HTTP post call "Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL"

Tags: angular

Here is my http post request from angular

```
    function test(){
    let fileData = {'test':'test'};
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Host': 'usertoken',
                'Authorization': 'xyz',
                'SOAPAction:': 'test'
              });
 let options = { headers: headers };

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:5050/api/bond/validatePolicy/106881706', fileData, options)
    }
```

post service giving error "Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL"

while the same exact url working fine at fiddler script as well as at postman ?

what I am doing wrong ?

exact error 
error = DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10244:31 at XMLHttpRequest.proto.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try to console your API URL and check if it coming properly?

Comment: and also you are initializing options twice with the same code.

Comment: exact same in console , please ignore option written twice , its typo error

Comment: it will be better if you share your fiddler to have a look once

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm getting a similar error and it makes little sense to me.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: I had the same error, and found that it was related to Url's that I had defined using a constant plus a string combination.  Like PROTOCOL + '://' + location.hostname + ":" + PORT + "/".   I changed all quotes to single-quote mark and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the polyfills.js threw me off and had nothing to do with the issue. I had an API call that had a malformed URL (something like http://someurl:someport/apiundefinded), but instead of referencing that URL, it threw the polyfills error.

Once I corrected the bad API endpoint, everything worked as-expected.

I put a break point at the location were Chrome noted the error was being throw to identify the actual URL causing issues.